# Django - How to make a relationship in Django that is related to a multiple ManyToManyField model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am a django beginner.

I have two models here that are used in another model as a ManyToManyField :

In **models.py** :

```
class Likelihoods(models.Model):
Likelihood = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
Param = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Consequences(models.Model):
Consequence = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
Param = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Inherent_risks(models.Model):
    Likelihood = models.ManyToManyField(Likelihoods, related_name= 'InherentRisk_Likelihood')
    Consequence = models.ManyToManyField(Consequences, related_name= 'InherentRisk_Consequence')
```

After this, i added it to another model in order to create a form name `Hira`.

```
class Hira(models.Model):

    Activity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Risk_Description = models.TextField(default="***")
    PBS = models.ManyToManyField(PBS)
    Physical_control = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Administrative_control = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Instrumented_control = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Inherent_Risk = models.ForeignKey(Inherent_risks, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Inherent_risk' )
```

The **form.py** :

```
class HiraForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hira
        fields = '__all__'
```

The question :
[The form i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGlqU.png)
I can't choose both a `likelihood` and a `consequence` (not even any data).
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you create entries of the Inherent_Risk Model to choose from? Maybe before that you would need to create entries of Likelihoods and Consequences as well so you can create the Inherent_Risk entries.

Comment: @EliuS I may not have been very precise, but in fact I have predefined Likelihoods and consequences (from the admin tab). And then, I would like to be able to associate one of these Likelihoods and Consequences to the InherentRisk (there will be other types of risks in the future)

Comment: So there are entries in the Inherent_Risk table, correct? The form you linked looks like a typical form where there is no entry to choose from.

Comment: No there is no entries, what is needed is to be able to fill it in when I fill in the Hira form. Hira will contain several fields that can be filled in via the form.
When I fill in the "Inherent_Risk" field, I need to be able to select a Likelihood and a Consequence, that's why I can't put entries in Inherent_Risk.

Comment: You could have an additional view where you create the Inherent_Risk entries first. Alternatively you could add the fields forms.ModelFormFields for Likelihoods and Consequences to HiraForm and then create the Inherent_Risk entry before saving the Hira entry. Also you could just remove the Inherent_Risks model and add the two fields directly to Hira model.

Comment: I agree with Eliu. The default model from does not offer the creation of "child" objects. You can only assign and save a pre existing model to `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField`. Your options are: **1.)** display 3 forms a) likelyhood-form b) consequences-form c) hira form. Your view then needs to save a and b first. and then can save and assign c. OR **2.)** Give Hira-form the fields of likelyhood and consequences and overwrite the logic of hira-form `.save()`method. Let it first save likelyhodd and consequences and afterwards the hira object.